# Compiling a program in a loop with qsub

Tags: bash, makefile, intel-fortran, qsub

I want to compile a program in a bash for loop. When I run the program from the command line it will compile but when I use qsub it doesn't compile.

Is there something I am missing?

Regards,

John

Bash File

```
  #!/bin/bash
  #$ -N runTest
  #$ -m e
  #$ -r y

  cd /afs/crc.nd.edu/user/private/NDPICMCC/SAFECODE

  thisDir="SAFECODE"
  t=2000

  originalGUILine="pres = 7.6E1"
  oldGUILine="$originalGUILine"
  GUIfile="GUIVars.f90"

  for (( i = -3 ; i <= 1 ; i=i+1 ))
    do
        p="7.6E$i"
        newGUILine="pres = $p"
        sed -i "s/$oldGUILine/$newGUILine/g" "$GUIfile"
        oldGUILine="$newGUILine"

        make clean >& /dev/null
        make 1D >& /dev/null
        make 1D

        ./PressurePIC

        cp "Anode_ele_eng.csv" "../results/T_${t}_P_${p}_Energies.csv"
    done

  sed -i "s/$oldGUILine/$originalGUILine/g" "$GUIfile"
```

makefile

```
  CC=ifort
  OPTIONS = -warn noalign -autodouble
  PRNG = luxury.f90
  MAIN = NDPIC1D.v0.f90 GUIVars.f90 GlobalVars.f90 StatisticalDistribution.f90 Emission.f90
  TODO = ParticleInCell.f90 MonteCarloCollision.f90 Transformations.f90
  EXE = PressurePIC

  all:
    @$(CC) $(PRNG) $(MAIN) $(TODO) -o $(EXE) $(OPTIONS)

  1D:
    @$(CC) $(PRNG) $(MAIN) $(TODO) -o $(EXE) $(OPTIONS)

  2D:
    @$(CC) $(PRNG) $(MAIN) $(TODO) -o $(EXE) $(OPTIONS)

  clean:
    @rm *.mod $(EXE)

  run:
    @./$(EXE)

  info:
    @echo $(EXE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what flavour of `qsub` you are using so this may not help ...

Try including

```
#$ -V
```

at the start of your script.  On some systems which process `qsub` it ensures that environment variables are exported from your environment to the environment in which the script eventually runs.  These environments are not, generally, the same.